# Read ASCII file, store in array, print

Tags: c++, arrays, ascii, iostream

The task is as follows:

> *Create an ASCII text and a C++ program to read it.  Print the Shipped date, part number, first name, last name, company name from the ASCII text.*

I had to create my own ASCII text.  I tested it, and was able to read it successfully.   Now, I'm having trouble reading character by character and sending to an array so that I can filter out the data I don't want to display.  I will show my ASCII text file followed by the code I'm using to read it.

```
04/12/11   D50625    74444    James   Lehoff      Rotech
04/12/11   D60752    75255    Janet   Lezar       Rotech
04/12/11   D40295    74477    Bill    McHenry     Rotech
04/12/11   D23745    74470    Diane   Kaiser      Rotech
04/12/11   D50892    75155    Helen   Richardson  NapTime
```

(I don't know why this format won't work...sorry...its not important for the task)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//initialize array
    const int MAXROWS = 5;
    const int MAXCOLS = 64;
    int ship_array [MAXROWS][MAXCOLS];
    int row,col;


string filename = "/Users/Jimmy/Desktop/shipped.txt";
string line;
ifstream inFile;


inFile.open(filename.c_str());   //opens ASCII file
if (inFile.fail())   //checks for successful open
{
    cout << "\nThefile was not successfully opened"
    << "\n Please check that the file currently exists." << endl;
    exit(1);
}

cout << "\nThe file has been successfully opened for reading.\n" << endl;

///////////code to read and output the data will go here///////////////////


cout << "Shipped Date   Part Number   First name   Last Name   Company Name";

    //cycle through rows and columns//
    row=0;
    while(row<MAXROWS)
    {
        for (col=1; col<9; col++)  // STORE SHIPPED DATE
        {
            ship_array[row][col] = get(filename.c_str());
            cout << ship_array[row][col];       //DISPLAY SHIPPED DATE
        }
        for (col=22; col<27; col++) //STORE PART NUMBER
        {
            ship_array[row][col] = get(filename.c_str());
            cout << ship_array[row][col];        //DISPLAY PART NUMBER
        }
        for (col=31; col<36; col++) // STORE FIRST NAME
        {
            ship_array[row][col] = get(filename.c_str());
            cout << ship_array[row][col];        //DISPLAY FIRST NAME
        }
        for (col=39; col< 49; col++) // STORE LAST NAME
        {
            ship_array[row][col] = get(filename.c_str());
            cout << ship_array[row][col];        //DISPLAY LAST NAME
        }
        for (col=51; col<65; col++) // STORE COMPANY NAME
        {
            ship_array[row][col] = get(filename.c_str());
            cout << ship_array[row][col];         //DISPLAY COMPANY NAME
        }
    }

    inFile.close();

return 0;
}
```

I KNOW the error is where I'm storing my values FROM the ASCII text to my array.  I thought get() was for reading one character at a time but it doesn't work.  Please point me in the right direction.

EDIT

I changed my code a bit.  I tried something new.  This gave me a few zeros.  I didn't even bother going further down.  My variables and initializations aren't right and I don't know why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//initialize array
    const int MAXROWS = 5;
    const int MAXCOLS = 64;
    int ship_array [MAXROWS][MAXCOLS];
    int row,col;
//initialize input stream
string ascii_data = "/Users/Jimmy/Desktop/shipped.txt";
ifstream data;
stringstream ss(ascii_data);
data.open(ascii_data.c_str());   //opens ASCII file
if (data.fail())   //checks for successful open
{
    cout << "\nThefile was not successfully opened"
    << "\n Please check that the file currently exists." << endl;
    exit(1);
}

cout << "\nThe file has been successfully opened for reading.\n" << endl;


cout << "Shipped Date     Part Number     First name     Last Name     Company      Name" << endl;

    //cycle through rows and columns//
    row=0;
    while(row<MAXROWS)
    {
        for (col=1; col<9; col++)  // STORE SHIPPED DATE
        {
            ss >> ship_array[0][col];
            cout << ship_array[row][col];//DISPLAY SHIPPED DATE
        }
        for (col=22; col<27; col++) //STORE PART NUMBER
        {
            ss >> ship_array[row][col];        //DISPLAY PART NUMBER
        }
        for (col=31; col<36; col++) // STORE FIRST NAME
        {
            ss >> ship_array[row][col];        //DISPLAY FIRST NAME
        }
        for (col=39; col< 49; col++) // STORE LAST NAME
        {
            ss >> ship_array[row][col];        //DISPLAY LAST NAME
        }
        for (col=51; col<65; col++) // STORE COMPANY NAME
        {
            ss >> ship_array[row][col];         //DISPLAY COMPANY NAME
        }
        row++;
    }

    data.close();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `some_int_in_an_array = get(filename);` Are you sure `get()` returns an int? Is that what you want? Is it reading into the "filename" string or is it reading from "filename"? If it's the first then your naming is horrible, but more importantly: how is it "hooked" to `inFile`?

Comment: My intention is to stream an ASCII text to my program, then drop it character by character into my array, then output those values.

Comment: You don't need the array. Just filter the data or print it as you read it, line by line.

Comment: the problem is, the data from my ASCII text file has 6 columns of data, and I'm only asked to print 5 columns.

Comment: Read a tutorial about text input in C++... But you should wonder about composed names like Von Neuman, or De La Vega, or ...